# Como transformar(cortar) somente um lado do elemento com css?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

preciso fazer um background como esse da imagem, consegui fazer nos dois lados usando o `transform: skew()`, mas preciso fazer só do lado direito como na imagem!
Agradeço a ajuda!!

[image]

o meu está assim preciso deixar como na imagem acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo que usei pra fazer:

```
<div  style="" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
            <p>PRÊMIOS EM DESTAQUE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-4 col-xs-6" style="padding: 2px; background-color: #e9670e; top: 51px"></div>

div{
   padding-top: 10px; 
   background-color: #e9670e; 
   top: 15px; color: white
}
```

Comment: O que voce tem até o momento?

Comment: Não consegue fazer esse efeito com border? aí dá pra fazer apenas de um lado.

Comment: Paulo editei a pergunta e coloquei oque tenho até agora.

Comment: Cadê o CSS que faz o efeito ?

Comment: ta no style, vou colocar separado

Comment: Eita... mas aí não vai dar certo mesmo. Você tem que criar uma `class` e chamar no elemento. Isso é uma boa prática. Usar o CSS INLINE não é uma boa prática, a não ser que seja para e-mails.

Comment: Atualizei meu POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.efeito{
      color: white;
      height: 0px;
      line-height: 0;
      border-top: 40px solid transparent;
      border-right: 40px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 40px solid orange;
      line-height: 40px;
      text-indent: 20px;
      width: 50%;
      font-family: "Roboto";
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bolder;
      position: relative;
}
.efeito:after{
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background-color: orange;
      height: 4px;
      width: 30px;
      top: 36px;
      right: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 efeito">
  PRÊMIOS EM DESTAQUE
</div>
```

Comment: farei o mesmo hauhauha

Comment: Sim. Edita sua pergunta e coloca seu código. Apenas o necessário. A DIV e o CSS. Coloca na sua pergunta, aqui não. Difícil de entender.

Comment: valeu, funcionou!!